# edit text, textWatcher called multiples

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textwatcher

i have a custom `editText`, with `TextWatcher`.
I have to formate user input after text changed.

Every think works fine, but in case of space the method `afterTextChanged` was called multiples.

FYI : I use `android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"` but still called multiples.

Comment: Also i have tried removeTextWatcher and add it again, but i have the same issue.

Comment: If you modify text you will get another callback call *because* of your change.

Comment: @natario yes i know that, my problems is when i add space i have callback called many times.